# Storing texture ID's for fast global retrieval

Tags: opengl, java, textures, resource-management

Simple question:

What is the fastest way to retrieve a texture ID, given an enum value? Say I have 100 textures, what would be the fastest way to get one texture ID?

Make a texture manager with a `HashMap<TextureEnum, int>` so I can call `TextureManager.get(TextureEnum.button_hover)`? (example, I know hashmaps are slow).

Comment: There is rarely a universally best way to do something. Questions like this just invite opinions. Since your requirements are poorly defined, there are lots of strategies that would work.

Comment: Agreed. Changed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why do you think hash maps are slow? For run time data they are quite fast!

An easy and good to start with approach is using a `std::unordered_map` which maps `GLuint` texture ids to `std::string` names.

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

unordered_map<string, GLuint> textures;
```

Then you could expand this to an easy manager by providing functions to create, get and delete textures. I wrote down this three functions without testing, but I think it is helpful anyway.

Function to create a new texture, load image data to it and add it to the system.

```
void TextureCreate(string Name, string ImagePath, bool Mipmapping = false;)
{
    // load image file from disk
    // ...

    GLuint id;
    // create OpenGL texture
    // ...

    textures.insert(make_pair(Name, id));
}
```

Function to get a created texture.

```
GLuint TextureGet(string Name)
{
    auto i = textures.find(Name);
    if(i == textures.end())
    {
        cout << "Texture with this name doesn't exist." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    return i.second;
}
```

Function to delete a texture from the system.

```
void TextureDelete(string Name)
{
    auto i = textures.find(Name);
    if(i == textures.end())
    {
        cout << "Texture with this name doesn't exist." << endl;
        return;
    }

    GLuint id = i.second;
    // delete OpenGL texture
    // ...

    textures.erase(i);
}
```

Use case example.

```
// initialization
TextureCreate("button", "images/button/default.png");
TextureCreate("button hover", "images/button/hover.png");
Button.texture = TextureGet("button");

// on hover event
Button.texture = TextureGet("button hover");

// on blur event
Button.texture = TextureGet("button");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I'm using Java, but I get the point.